# How to pick a node from the parent in JavaFx 8

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8

Is there any way to pick a node from the parent using double coordinates? I heard of `impl_pickNode` method, but it doesn't use double coordinates and it doesn't seem to be good practice to use deprecated methods.

Comment: with double coordinates you mean its "absolute" position ? You might need to implement it yourself iterating over its children. Did you have a look at this ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pickOnBoundsProperty

Answer (score -1):

Did you solve you problem? If not, this should help: http://fxexperience.com/2016/01/node-picking-in-javafx/

This is the code that replaces `impl_pickNode` in the SceneBuilder implementation.

Basically you recursively go through all children, starting at the root node of the scenegraph, and check whether the coordinates are inside this node. If this is the case, you further follow down the path, until you find the leaf node.  When doing this, you also should check if the Node for example `isVisible` or `isMouseTransparent` as well as respecting the z-order.